# PowerBI embedded filters not propagating to bookmarks

Tags: powerbi-embedded

We have a multi-page embedded report with which we pass filters in on page load using the following syntax:

```
{
  "responseCode": "RES.20000",
  "responseMessage": "Success",
  "data": {
    "token": "xxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    "embeddedReportURL": "<myurl>/ReportSection",
    "reportId": "<id>",
    "filters": [
      {
        "table": "SomeTable",
        "column": "SomeColumn",
        "value": "123"
      },
      {...}
    ]
  }
}
```

When we click on a button to navigate to another page via a bookmark, these filters are not propagating to the next page.  Our we doing something wrong in how we are setting the filters?  Is there a work around if this is just the way it is?

Answer (score 0):

When you save a bookmark you save the state of the report including the filters that were applied in that moment, so even if you load a report with filters, once you use bookmark you will get back to the state of the bookmark. What you can do is to apply the filters after the bookmark.

Answer (score 0):

There is an event to capture the bookmark applied event. You can apply the filter after the bookmark is applied using the following code snippet.

```
// Listen on bookmark applied event and log the applied bookmark name to browser console.
report.on("bookmarkApplied", (event) => {
    console.log(event.detail.name);
});
```